# vert.x "405 Method Not Allowed" response not adding allow header

Tags: vert.x

As per this document, https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_route_match_failures Vert.x-Web will signal a 405 error If a route matches the path but doesn’t match the HTTP Method, but as per Mozilla document https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405 response should contain `allow` header. Is there any reason why it's not added in response?

It only adds `content-length` header

Vert.x Version - 4.3.4

Answer (score 2):

Due to the way vert.x keeps track of the handlers internally (in a skip list) it is not trivial to identify which handlers would trigger the right state, so, we can clearly identify which methods are invalid, but not so trivial to say which ones are valid.

This is something we are planning to improve in the future releases, as we would like to see the internal routing algorithm to move from a skip list to a compressed tree.

With a tree, it will be possible to detect undoubtedly which methods are valid or not.